Focus state of badge/tag cog on dark-mode homepage is all light grey- gear/cog icon is not visible
The focus state of the gear/cog on the next badge and watched tags cards on the homepage in dark mode has a grey background, and the gear/cog is either the same colour or invisible. Effectively, the gear icon is invisible in the focus state. This doesn't happen in the user profile page. Pls fix.

Thanks - will sort
